# GeForce 210 support for OpenGL 4.x on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia-geforce, kubuntu, opengl

The GeForce 210 card has hardware OpenGL 3.x capable. Is it possible to make that the card supports OpenGL 4.1 at least? Maybe with some software library?

PS. The computer has installed Kubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to make that the card supports OpenGL 4.1 at least?
>   Maybe with some software library?

No;  It is not possible;  OpenGL and DirectX support is based on the hardware.  The hardware you have cannot and does not support any version of OpenGL higher then 3.0.